# Android: How to save/restore data

Tags: android, android-sdcard

In my app I have a Linked List (I use the standard List()).
I want this list to be saved to the sd card (or the phone memory) every time the user exits the app and restore it every time the user starts the app.
How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `SharedPreferences` , refer the [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) , and this [tutorial](http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/54/using-sharedpreferences-example/) to understand how to do it :)

Comment: What if the list is not a primitive type?  From the android site "The SharedPreferences class provides a general framework that allows you to save and retrieve persistent key-value pairs of primitive data types"

Answer (score 0):

The [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) site has an excellent guide how you can store your data on the phone.