# Using the Internal Storage

Tags: android

In my app I have a Linked List (type List),
every time the user starts the app I want to restore the list from the Internal Storage (if there is a saved file on the Internal Storage) or create a new list (to be saved later on).

How can I use the read/write functions (on FileInputStream/FileOutputStream) to do it ?

Comment: :i think that you have already post a similar question about this : save/restore data  ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665339/android-how-to-save-restore-data/7665408#7665408

Comment: @Houcine it's different,
I read the doc on the developers guide as suggested in the previews post but the actual question is how to use those read/write functions.

for example read returns an int, how can I use it to restore a saved List...

Comment: @Belgi hello again. Following you from Q to Q, it _seems_ that what you're really interested in is called `SharedPreferences`

Comment: refer this question and tell me if it helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519820/how-to-save-arraylist-in-an-bundle-object

Comment: @Laurent'- isn't SharedPreferences only works for primitive data ?
(and thanks for the help!)

Comment: @Laurent'- I also checked out the link, I think that the holder won't work after the app closes, that why I want to save the data to the internal storage.

Comment: @Belgi : did you see the link of my answer about using SharedPreferences to save an Object ??

Comment: @Houcine - sorry I missed tag, I answerd in the previews comment : "I think that the holder won't work after the app closes, that why I want to save the data to the internal storage"

Comment: @Belgi : lol i saw it , no problem :). know you want to save your Object in the internat storage and restore it later  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer this Question , it's about **how to Save an Object**  **by using** `SharedPreferences` : [how android SharedPreferences save/store object ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145606/how-android-sharedpreferences-save-store-object)

**EDIT :**  refer this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625496/android-how-to-save-an-object-to-file) , its is about how to save / restore object using internal storage

Comment: I don't see how that post helps : it's about transfering object from one activity another...

Answer (score 0):

```
//save file into internal 
try {
                    URL url = new URL("your url");
                     java.io.BufferedInputStream in = new java.io.BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

                       FileOutputStream fos ;
                       fos = openFileOutput("test11.xml",Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
                        java.io.BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fos,1024);
                        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                        int x=0;
                        while((x=in.read(data,0,1024))>=0){
                            bout.write(data,0,x);               
                        }
                        fos.flush();
                        bout.flush();
                        fos.close();
                        bout.close();
                        in.close();

                    fos.close();

                    Toast.makeText(
                            AndroidInternalStorageActivity.this, 
                            fileName + " saved", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

//List of internal files                
 void ShowSavedFiles(){
        SavedFiles = getApplicationContext().fileList();
        Log.e("file path is :",Arrays.toString(SavedFiles));
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter
        = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                SavedFiles);

        listSavedFiles.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

//Delete internal file 

    File dir = getFilesDir();
        File file = new File(dir, "test.xml");
        Log.e("file path : ",file.toString());
        boolean deleted = file.delete();
        if(deleted)
        {
            Log.e("delete ","true");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e("delete","false");
        }
```